# Как работать с -d, -sourthpath, -classpath и в чем ошибка?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать на курсах java, ранее с программированием почти не сталкивался. Задали ДЗ, и нужно скомпилировать файл, и что б классы поместились в 1 папку, исходники были в другой и т.д. Так вот, подскажите пожалуйста (желательно с примерами), как пользоваться командами -d, -sourthpath, -classpath и при компиляции файла мне выдает такие ошибки, я так понимаю 2 и 3 последствие 1й ошибки, а вот что не так не пойму. Файл в той директории есть, все как надо, что оно от меня хочет? :(
вот картинка http://cs402520.vk.me/v402520410/a907/yHPbLtIyRDk.jpg
За ранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Русский бы сначала выучили что ли...

По сути:

-sourcepath указывает на путь где лежат исходники
-classpath указывает путь где надо искать классы
-d указывает путь куда надо складывать скомпилированные объектники

Например:

```
javac -sourcepath c:\sample\myproject\src -cp c:\sample\myproject\classes -d c:\sample\myproject\classes pr1\MainClass.java
```

1. Компилятор будет искать класс pr1.MainClass.java в каталоге c:\sample\myproject\src
2. Полученные объектники (.class) файлы будет складывать в каталог c:\sample\myproject\classes
3. В том же каталоге будет искать внешние ссылки в вашем исходнике (ссылки на другие классы, если он есть) - это и есть CLASSPATH